# Json integer being read as java Boolean true

Tags: json, spring-boot, boolean

Inside a REST API request json body, I'm passing `"argument1":true` and it works. But I discovered that when using any number it converts it to true. Only when using explicitly `false` it turns into false. I'm using Spring Boot `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` and `@RestControllerAdvice` to handle all exceptions. How can I cast any exception when converting `534` to `true`?

Comment: Do you expect `argument1` to be of type boolean or int? I mean, you want spring binder to throw exception when `argument1` is integer and not boolean?

Comment: @noiaverbale, exactly as you stated. I want to reject any non boolean values (only true or false)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add in your controller a method annotated with `@InitBinder` and provide a custom boolean editor

```java
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
    webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Boolean.class, new CustomBooleanEditor("true", "false", false));
}
```

Spring registers a default [CustomBooleanEditor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/CustomBooleanEditor.html) mapping "true", "on", "yes" and any non zero number as `true` (also allowing empty value as `false`) throwing `IllegalArgumentException` when value is not valid.

You can either override it or provide your own implementation throwing a specific exception.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Could you please link any documentation towards this information? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not a much, but [InitBinder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-initbinder). Can't find a list of default converters/editor right now.

Comment: I don't get this working when having a @RequestBody.....so it is no forms just a rest endpoint.....should it work in that scenario also ?